# C# - Save multiple blobs into azure account

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, mqtt

I've got a simple project that use M2mqtt client library to connect to HiveMQ broker. When a message arrives an event will fire, the fact is I can receive up to 100 messages per second and the program is able to processing just 20 messages per second.

```
 HiveMQClient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += HiveMQClient_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
```

So, I have all the HiveMQ logs and telemetry and i can clearly see that the messages arrives in my application with the right rate (100 per second) but the strange thing is that the CPU of the PC where the client program is hosted runs at 10% of its capacity.

I was wondering if I need to "multi thread the event" or there is something that I'm missing.

Thank you all

**EDIT**

Inside the `MqttMsgPublishReceived` event i've got a `ThreadPool` that stores the messages that i receive inside an **azure blob account**. After some reviews I understood that this is the problem (thanks @Hans Kilian ).

Now i've got an azure blob storage account, standard configuration) that accepts only 30 calls per second. I tried to update into the premium tier but it is only for virtual machine VHD images.

Anybody knows how to improve these numbers?

Comment: Depending on how you process the messages, your bottleneck could be somewhere else. Usually, in the systems I've worked on, the database is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

The `MqttMsgPublishReceived` call back runs on the clients network thread, if you are interested in performance then you should not be doing any real work in this callback.

For high performance applications the model is normally to use the `MqttMsgPublishReceived` method to place the incoming message in a local queue in the client and have a thread pool consuming messages from that queue.

This becomes even more important when using QOS 1 or 2 messages as the broker will not send the next message until the `MqttMsgPublishReceived` has returned and the QOS handshake completes.

As @HandKilian says in the comments things like databases can also be a bottle neck, but using a thread pool combined with a database connection pool can help as it makes sure you are not building and tearing down a connection to the database for each message.

Comment: You are right, let me edit my question with more details